# Use index of geometry inside user-defined function

Tags: postgis

```
create function are_close_to_each_other(g1 geometry, g2 geometry)
returns boolean
language sql immutable as $$
   select ST_DWithin(g1, g2, 100);
$$;

select x.*, y.*
from sometable x, sometable y
where are_close_to_eachother(x.geom, y.geom);
```

I have an index on sometable (geom). Will this index be used inside function are_close_to_each_other? If not, how to make it use it?

Comment: It's been decades since using a FROM table list was best practice. Nowadays, the JOIN keyword is the only appropriate way to add tables to the base FROM table, which also lobs a softball at the optimizer in generating a query plan.

Comment: while `st_dwithin` is [`parallel safe`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/parallel-safety.html), your function is `unsafe` (by default), so while the spatial index will be used, the seq scan on the 1st table will be much slower when using your function rather than joining on `st_dwithin` directly

Comment: Yes, that's also important. Unless you define it as parallel safe it won't be able to run in parallel (using multiple CPUs).

Comment: Thanks @JGH for pointing this out. Never knew about this really fundamental and important thing, to mark pretty much all immutable functions as parallel safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be used the same way it would be used if the query looked like this:

```
select x.*, y.*
from sometable x, sometable y
where ST_DWithin(x.geom, y.geom, 100);
```

[Documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) states that `ST_DWithin` uses available indexes.

You can make sure by running:

```
explain analyze
select x.*, y.*
from sometable x, sometable y
where are_close_to_each_other(x.geom, y.geom);
```

If there is "index scan" in the output it means that the indexes were used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Am I correct to assume the reason the index is used is because geometries are passed to sql-functions by reference, not by value?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Index  scan has to be performed on an indexed column/expression not on a specific value.

Comment: I was just thinking, how the function can know about the index.

Comment: Because `ST_DWithin` is an index aware function, as mentioned in the documentation. And your function simply calls it with your own argument. 

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html
*This function call includes a bounding box comparison that makes use of any indexes that are available on the geometries.*